# AS3 setInterval double, triple issue

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, setinterval

I'm having a setInterval AS3 problem.Let me explain: I'm making a game with a timer, lets for example give its instance, timer1.every 500 milliseconds timer1 moves to left 25 times (timer1.x-=25) and when timer1 hitTests finish1 (if(timer1.hitTestObject(finish1))) it goes to the you lose scene.and you have to replay the level.When I hit replay and enter the scene the speed increases in the setInterval by double and if I lose again, triple and so on.How do fix this? It's very important that I have it fixed soon.thanks

Comment: Just a thought... Maybe you should call clearInterval() and pass the id of your initial interval that you can get as a return from setInterval() call. This would prevent duplicated action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like multiple instances of `timer1` are continuing to run.

1 instance of `timer1` runs at original speed.

2 instances of `timer1` runs at double speed.
etc.

Ensure that the original `timer1` is stopped, deleted or killed off before changing scene.

You may want to reference the function `clearInterval`.